# TypeError: Cannot read property of null [while calling external(defer)/internal JSFile]

Tags: javascript, dom

The Html/JS(vanilla) script below ,gives the following error **[when used with both an internal script aswell as an external JS file (using the "defer" keyword)]** -
How could this error be resolved?

**Chrome**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of null
```

Firefox

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

```js
//StackOverflow Error - Filename empty (Not sure how to insert JS filename?).But this script works fine on Local codeeditor(VsCode).

document.getElementById("change1").onclick(function(){
  
    document.getElementById("tx1").innerHTML = "tx1 changed with JS";
 console.log("Change1  btn pressed");   
    }
)

document.querySelector("change2").addeventlistener("click",()=>{
  
    document.getElementById("tx2").innerHTML = "tx2 changed with JS";
 console.log("Change2 btn pressed");   
    },false
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<<device-width>>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Event2</title>
    <script src= "testJS_event2.js" defer ></script>
    

</head>
<body>
 <div>
     
     <p id="tx1">tx1 <--- this element is null </p>
     <h1 id="tx2">tx2 <--- this element is also null  </h1><br>
     <button id = "change1">Change1</button>
     <button id = "change2">Change2</button>
 </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put your scripts right before `</body>`, or you can wrap your code in an `onload` event. The issue is your script runs before DOM is ready, which means elements like `change1` and `change2` might not be available yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to assign function to the `onclick` event attribute of the element
- For `querySelector` you need to access the element with a `#` as you are accessing the element with its `id`
- There was a typo for `addEventListener`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=<<device-width>>, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Event2</title>
  <script defer="defer">
    window.onload = function() {
      //StackOverflow Error - Filename empty (Not sure how to insert JS filename?).But this script works fine on Local codeeditor(VsCode).

      document.getElementById("change1").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("tx1").innerHTML = "tx1 changed with JS";
        console.log("Change2  btn pressed");
      };

      document.querySelector("#change2").addEventListener("click", () => {

        document.getElementById("tx2").innerHTML = "tx2 changed with JS";
        console.log("Change2 btn pressed");
      }, false);
    }
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <p id="tx1">tx1
      <!--- this element is null-->
    </p>
    <h1 id="tx2">tx2
      <!--- this element is also null -->
    </h1>
    <br>
    <button id="change1">Change1</button>
    <button id="change2">Change2</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Though [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) is used and document is parsed, the defer script will fire before `DOMContentLoaded`, hence the error.

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before
>   firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded
>   event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.

Comment: Thanks for the solution(1 upvote!).On a sidenote ,how did you insert the script filename in the StackOverflow editor. I am getting a script error.

Comment: @starzar I haven't inserted the script actually, as suggested by xrq0, you can either add your code in `window.onload` or put you script just before `body` tag ends

Comment: `getElementById` returns  HTMLElement or undefined. HTMLElement does not have onclick property, You need to bind a click event listener to it.

Comment: @MorloMbakop you could call it an _event attribute_ and no binding isn't the only way

Comment: @MorloMbakop yep, you can test it

Comment: @shrys No,I was asking about the Stackoveflow editor(Run Code Snippet) above.My script is not running,it does not detect the Js script on pasting it in the JS block provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Javascript is executed before you page is fully load, so it can find your elements.

Use [window.onload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and it will be good !

Or you can put your `<script src= "testJS_event2.js" defer ></script>` at the end of your body (better solution for loading time)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have typo in your code, `addEventListener` not `addeventlistener`.
2. `getElementById` returns `HTMLElement` or undefined. `HTMLElement` does not have onclick property, You need to bind a click event listener to it.
3. Lastly, you can only query the DOM once it is fully loaded. You JS execute before the code DOM is loaded. That is why the DOM elements your are querying are null/undefined.

You can also bind the onlick event in your butto directly. Here is a working sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Event2</title>
  <script src="testJS_event2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p id="tx1">tx1 <--- this element is null </p>
    <h1 id="tx2">tx2 <--- this element is also null </h1> <br>
    <button id="change1">Change1</button>
    <button id="change2">Change2</button>
    <button onclick="change3()">Change3</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("change1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("tx1").innerHTML = "tx1 changed with JS";
    console.log("Change1  btn pressed");
  });

  document.querySelector("#change2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("tx2").innerHTML = "tx2 changed with JS";
    console.log("Change2 btn pressed");
  });
};

function change3() {
  console.log("Change 3 clicked .......");
}
```